# ejb interceptor for a stateless session bean,how can i invoke a stateful session bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, ejb, session-bean

A class is a stateful session bean with a loginUser property.
B class is a stateless session bean with a method addAUser.
how does the interceptor check wether A.loginUser is null when B.addUser method be used.
thank u .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem cant be solved by injecting statefull into stateless. Because this is a EJB anti-pattern. Have a look at [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html). It provides session-scoped beans like Spring. the only limitation is that its available only since JEE6.